# Inconsistent Accessibility using lists

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scope

I'm trying to create a list of class instances for storing information, but I'm getting this error:

`Error  1   Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<POS_System.ReportReciepts>' is less accessible than property 'POS_System.Reports24Hours.recieptlist'`

Any clue why? I've tried figuring out but I have no idea whats throwing this. Heres my code where the error is being thrown and my class. Thanks!

```
public partial class Reports24Hours : Form
{
    string category = "";
    public int WhichReciept = 0;
    public static List<ReportReciepts> recieptlist { get; set; } //Error here
    ...
}
```

.

```
class ReportReciepts
{
    public string[] Quantity { get; set; }
    public string[] ItemName { get; set; }
    public string[] Price { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ReportReceipts needs to be Public. Essentially you're making a public list of items, but the type of item is private, so no one can see it. This should work:

```
public partial class Reports24Hours : Form
{
    string category = "";
    public int WhichReciept = 0;
    public static List<ReportReciepts> recieptlist { get; set; } //Error here
    ...
}



public class ReportReciepts
{
    public string[] Quantity { get; set; }
    public string[] ItemName { get; set; }
    public string[] Price { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've done this before and I didn't need to make the class public, not quite sure why. It works now that the class is public though, so whatever. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `ReportReciepts` `public`. The default access modifier for a class is `internal`, but you're attempting to return a `List` of `ReportReciepts` from a `public` property. Any type exposed via a public property must itself be public.