# Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'TagHandler' is less accessible than field 'EditTag.tag'

Tags: c#, forms

I want to create a form where I can edit a field of my class `TagHandler`. 
So I decided to pass as a paramter to form's constructor `TagHandler tag` where `tag` - is a tag I want to edit. In my form I've got a field `tag` which I edit and then get its data.
For example in my main form I've got a listbox with `MouseDoubleClick` method

```
void listBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int index = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
    TagHandler tg = listData[index];

    EditTag edit = new EditTag(tg);
    if (edit.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        listData[index] = edit.Tag as TagHandler;
    }
}
```

Where `EditTag` is a form

```
public partial class EditTag : Form
{
    public TagHandler tag { set; get; }
    public EditTag(TagHandler tag)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.CenterToParent();
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
        this.MaximizeBox = false;

        this.tag = tag;
        this.label2.Text = tag.Tag;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tag.Data = richTextBox1.Text;
        this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```

But I've got such errors

**Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'XmlMissionEditor.TagHandler' is less accessible than property 'XmlMissionEditor.EditTag.tag'**

**Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'XmlMissionEditor.TagHandler' is less accessible than method 'XmlMissionEditor.EditTag.EditTag(XmlMissionEditor.TagHandler)'**

What's the problem? I even set `tag` field as `public` but it still shows the same error.
My class `TagHandler` looks like this

```
[Serializable]
class TagHandler
{
    private string data;
    private string tag;
    private Color color;
    private List<AttributeHandler> attributes;

    public TagHandler(string tag, bool close)
    {
        attributes = new List<AttributeHandler>();
        if (close)
        {
            string s = "/" + tag;
            this.tag = s;
        }
        else
        {
            this.tag = tag;
        }
    }

    public string Tag
    {
        get { return tag; }
        set { tag = value; }
    }

    public string Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; }
    }

    ...other methods

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are the problem:

```
public TagHandler tag { set; get; }
public EditTag(TagHandler tag)
```

The latter is a public method in a public class. Therefore all its parameters and its return type should be public too - otherwise you're saying "You can call this, but you can't know about the type you're calling it with" (or what it's returning, if it's the return type that's not public. Likewise the type of the property has to be public.

Either make the constructor and property internal or make the `TagHandler` type public.

Comment: Isn't the compiler also complaining about the public `tag` property?

Comment: @user1432980: What do you mean by "the same classes"? Yes, they're just classes - the fact that `EditTag` is a form is completely irrelevant to this. You've got a public constructor in a public class which uses a non-public type as a constructor parameter. You can't do that - it means the constructor would make no sense to code outside the current assembly.

Comment: Hm hm..I hardly can explain what do I mean now...Well whatever.

Answer (score 5):

You should set `TagHandler` class as public

```
public class TagHandler
```

You can take a look at these questions:

- [Inconsistent Accessibility using lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986063/inconsistent-accessibility-using-lists)
- [Inconsistent accessibility error C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805610/inconsistent-accessibility-error-c-sharp)
- [Inconsistent accessibility issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191036/inconsistent-accessibility-issue)